# How to have multiple arg parameters in python function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have used this code

```
def doubarg_twice (func, arg, arg):
    return func(func(arg, arg))
```

to design a function in python that executes another double argument function twice. The problem is that the "arg" parameter is doubled. I want the function that gets applied twice to have multiple arguments though. How can I do that?

thanks in advance!

Comment: try to understand first what is the output of ```def doubarg_twice (func, arg, arg):
    return (func(arg, arg))``` and why you get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to repeat `arg` in the parameter list to use it twice inside.

But since `func()` takes two arguments, the outer call needs two copies of the result of the inner call. You can do this with a variable.

```
def doubarg_twice(func, arg):
    temp = func(arg, arg)
    return func(temp, temp)
```